# Specializing Union Literal type property

Tags: typescript

I want to have a generic container type, which I then can specialize and check during runtime.

```js
type AllTypes = {
    type: 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc';
    value: any;
};

type A = AllTypes & { type: 'aaa' };

const all: AllTypes = {
    type: 'aaa',
    value: 123,
};

if (all.type == 'aaa') {
    const a: A = all; // Error
}
```

If I use plain literals it works.

```js
type AllLitTypes = 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc';

type ALit = AllLitTypes & 'aaa';

const all: AllLitTypes = 'aaa';

if (all == 'aaa') {
    const a: ALit = all; // Ok
}
```

In my case the type literal of `AllTypes` comes from a library so I can not create the specific types first and combine them afterwards.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't automatically propagate unions from object properties up to the whole object; see [ms/TS#8289](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289) and other issues that link to it.  Do any of the approaches in [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NrvRaN) work for you?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on the failing use cases.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the github issues, there I find the explanation which made the behavior comprehensible [link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052#issuecomment-258653766). I was hoping for a less verbose way to achive the intended behavior but so be it.
My favorit is the destructioning (nice way of using it btw), my second favorit is simple the assertion (because we are all responsible programmer)

Comment: I see you have your own deleted answer; I'm not sure if you want to write that up yourself or you want me to write up my version of it.  Either way is fine with me; let me know.

Comment: No I frist red you comment wrong. Post it and get the credit

Comment: btw I used the word "destructure" when I should have used "spread"; they are sort of opposites of each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't do a lot of work to try to propagate [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) either upwards out of object properties or downwards into them.  That is, the compiler generally does not see the types `{foo: A} | {foo: B}` and `{foo: A | B}` to be equivalent.  You can look at [microsoft/TypeScript#8289](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289), [microsoft/TypeScript#12052](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052), and other related issues for a canonical answer, but the issue is that it is usually prohibitively expensive to do such type manipulation in a correct way.  In TypeScript 3.5 [some support was added for this kind of union transformation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#smarter-union-type-checking) but it only applies in limited circumstances, and your code is not doing it.

And since this doesn't happen, your `AllTypes` type is not seen as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), because it is not a union at all (only the `type` property is a union).  So checking the `type` property of `all` only serves to narrow the type of `type` and not the type of `all`.

---

The various approaches I'd take to solving this are:

**spreading:**

```
if (all.type == 'aaa') {
    const a: A = { ...all, type: all.type };
}
```

The compiler knows that `all.type` is of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"aaa"`, and [object spreading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#spread) will allow the compiler to combine the known non-narrowed type of `all` with the narrowed type of `{type: all.type}`.

**type assertion:**

You know something the compiler doesn't know, so it's a reasonable time to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it.  You need to be careful that you're not lying, but as long as you are sure you're telling the truth, this is an easy way to prevent errors:

```
if (all.type == 'aaa') {
    const a = all as A; 
}
```

**convert to a discriminated union:**

You can make the compiler transform an object type where a property is of a union type into a union of object types in which that property is not a union:

```
type DistributeUnionProp<T, K extends keyof T> =
    K extends unknown ?
    T[K] extends infer U ? U extends unknown ?
    { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? U : T[P] } :
    never : never : never;

type DiscriminatedAllTypes = DistributeUnionProp<AllTypes, "type">
/* type DistribAllTypes = {
    type: "aaa";
    value: any;
} | {
    type: "bbb";
    value: any;
} | {
    type: "ccc";
    value: any;
} */
```

By doing that to `AllTypes`, we get a discriminated union, which we can widen `all` to (after TS3.5 supported this):

```
const discrimAll: DiscriminatedAllTypes = all;
```

Once we do that, `discrimAll` is a discriminated union and can be narrowed by checking the discriminant property `type`:

```
if (discrimAll.type === 'aaa') {
    const a: A = discrimAll;
}
```

Each of those has their advantages.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-OhEmFZjAIo7TlmACJFJO1bgqgAqEk9rmMccaFRDAiKMiTryT3huQKicRSWT0fJuHdQSfMRgHgrH+ZntoXrdzXecdgPo9CE+k6RXwXKoTCOH5UHrBsHDIHtIObVt2zUJxTjgXhOiSVY63+KCEHSRZej6GhBkOCxRlKWAVEwiDsIcWRcCAA)

Comment: excellent and comprehensive answer!