# Type Definition : How to type an array to don't have tow specific value at the same time

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a type that can only have those specific values and nothing else :

```
[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,-1],[0,-1],[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1]
```

So to achieve that, I have made this type definition :

```js
type Steps = -1 | 0 | 1;
type Directions = [width:Steps, height:Steps];
```

But with this definition, I can do that :

```js
const invalidDirection : Directions = [0,0];
```

And I don't know how to restrict that, especially for `[0,0]`.

Comment: Your `invalidDirection1` and `invalidDirection2` are already prohibited, [see here](https://tsplay.dev/WP7OLm).  Can you ensure you provide a [mre] so that people don't chase down nonexistent issues?

Comment: You right, I will edit my question ^^'

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8Jgpm) work for you?  Check it against your use cases. If it meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: Yes, totally! But I don't understand how. Can you make an answer and explain with more details?

Comment: I will do so when I get a chance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *single, specific* [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type that corresponds to your intended `Directions`.  The single specific tuple type `[width: Steps, height: Steps]` will, by necessity, allow the first element ([labeled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements) `width`) to be chosen independently of the second element (labeled `height`).  And therefore nothing stops someone from choosing `0` for both elements.

---

If you want the two elements to depend on each other, you should write `Directions` as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of acceptable types.  You *could* do this manually, either as

```
type Directions = [width: Steps, height: Exclude<Steps, 0>] | 
  [width: Exclude<Steps, 0>, height: Steps];
```

or as

```
type Directions = [width: 0, height: Exclude<Steps, 0>] | 
  [width: Exclude<Steps, 0>, height: 0] |
  [width: Exclude<Steps, 0>, height: Exclude<Steps, 0>];
```

or as

```
type Directions = [width: 0, height: 1] | [width: 0, height: -1] | 
  [width: 1, height: 0] | [width: 1, height: 1] | 
  [width: 1, height: -1] | [width: -1, height: 0] | 
  [width: -1, height: 1] | [width: -1, height: -1];
```

(Note that while all three of those correspond to the same set of static
values, they are not considered mutually equivalent by the compiler and may exhibit different behavior in different contexts; see [Specializing Union Literal type property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556648/specializing-union-literal-type-property) for some discussion)

Any of those result in the desired behavior:

```
let dir: Directions;
dir = [0, -1]; // okay
dir = [1, -1]; // okay
dir = [1, 0]; // okay
dir = [1, 1]; // okay
dir = [0, 1]; // okay
dir = [-1, 1]; // okay
dir = [-1, 0]; // okay
dir = [-1, -1]; // okay
dir = [0, 0]; // error!
```

The first two approaches use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to filter types out of a union.  Note that the first one is terse enough that you may decide to use it directly.

---

On the other hand, you might want to do this *programmatically* from the definition of `Steps`, instead of manually... especially if you care about scaling the unions up or changing their values.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type Directions = Exclude<
    { [W in Steps]: {
        [H in Steps]: [width: W, height: H] }[Steps]
    }[Steps], [0, 0]>;
```

We are `Exclude`-ing the bad `[0, 0]` member from the expression `{[W in Steps]....}`, so let's examine that.  Here I'm making a nested "distributive object type" (as defined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)), which is making a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [indexing into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union.  Let's look at the inner one, `{[H in Steps]: [width: W, height: H]}[Steps]`:

The mapped type iterates `H` over each union member of `Steps` and makes a new three-keyed object type like `{"-1": [width: W, height: -1], "0": [width: W, height: 0], "1": [width: W, height: 1]}`.  We then index into that object type with the index `[-1 | 0 | 1]` which produces the three-member union `[width: W, height: -1] | [width: W, height: 0] | [width: W, height: 1]`.  You can hopefully see how the outer distributed object type plugs in `-1`, `0`, and `1` for `W` and produces a nine-element union.

And recall that we `Exclude` the `[width: 0, height: 0]` element from that union to get the eight-element union you desired!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZEwCuIA2BGJA3gFBFJlIAuAnjMgMoUQxRIC8SAtPgD5IAMSXrgDcJcpRrIAIgEsAThHgUZAe2At2AbQDuMgCYUAFgC4kDJlAA0SQxBkBzQxVMBRAB7xsGPRAA855ms+AD4AXUEkHX0jVw8vH39GQP5g61sHJ1MAqFDRUnJsCAokPXlTWQUlVXVRcVK5Nki+ay5cpAB6dqQVAGsQKnyyesbNXBbcNs7uvoG6+RGx-kmu3v7BkvmtRYnhDpWZ9eGtZqQdvem1uYatLmszqdXZ8iPI26Xdh4OrkbfWj-3Ls9Nk0gsskBA5HIVHIAIQkAC+JFAkFgCGQaEwOAATIQxORqLQzEkNJwePwIiI8WQCdJ5IplGoSVEDCZ+Gk7I5nEh3J5vH5skEwhFmTFuXE+YkLIL2RkuXxwtx1iLWTz4vzidKbBzMmLeQkBSlclSkIVivVynSqozakDriDSWDHodgaNxo6vraFqD-hcnkMXdt3YD-XbNCd7gC-RtQ28I77nTHFvKfU7vjdFn9zqnPcdvecIVDYQiSERkdA4IhUOgsNgAMy49Y0okWRpcCICIR5cRNir06pM3Qs0wndKc0wTYWD0Uj7Vc1qT6KsxajnXywRKqdLmVj04KyKb8fbnXz3jK0xvFdyvdn0lHrkTxXiG8X2fnibG03Ri2VBk1BMjE5M0+YNoy9B0Uw9EMwOTLNINArY7iDKMXjDRCIJAlDYyQ-90zzYDkJdX442zKDc3efNIWhOFEVLcByzRJAAAUoXsORwDAEBlHgBtu0kZtmFbMkO1OLt8T43srXURpVQldZxAISIAHUkBkYB+JyUxiHEbTyE0AAJFS1OyUJTBvRS71MPTwnhTRjLk8gbOM6xUKWYJRLIdoACoJEJCTfwHRdhws3cFyHNktVlN9rwPU5grXXg5JvZdXxC08YuSyKHVC0UX0y+L90C28Ip3B8kESmLcp3edPPaEtxE-c0kD8-sbVI+0gMjHDIgzYi4JQpNsLTbq0NgjCXXDQac1eQN0IIxM8M6obNCIya2pcmCpgLKiESAA)

Comment: Really, thanks! Your answer is wonderful, I have every possible way to define this, and I can generalize those techniques for different other case. I think I need to practice a bit to truly know how to make programmatically definition. But for static typing, It's much clearer for how to exclude values.